# Combine two views of an image to strengthen the output of a DL model

Tags: deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I have been trying this problem for weeks but to no avail.

My problem is:

Deep Learning Model has the following information:

INPUT: Sequence of Images

OUTPUT: What is happening in the image, i.e. categorise what is the activity happening from a sequence of 10 activities.

I have two cameras recording the same activity from two views, how could I combine those two views to improve the accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use DELF features, extract features of both similar images and combine them.

Comment: Ummm, actually I have problem with the combination part itself? How to actually combine those models?

Comment: Save features in csv for each image and use simple python script to combine. Say image1a image1b are two samples, convert their features in .csv, combine using python code.

Answer (score 0):

How to combine the two views is fully dependent on your understanding of the problem. Let me give you two different examples,

**CASE I**: when you review your training data, you can easily tell which camera is better for some data. e.g. one camera may capture everything useful, while the other camera may not due to possible occlusions (note: I am not saying one camera is always better than the other). In this case, you may use a later fusion technique to only fuse the two resulting features representing the sequences from two cameras.

**CASE II**: it is difficult for you to tell which camera is better. This basically indicates that you may not see performance boost after you consider both cameras, but maybe some small improvement.

Finally, when you say two cameras, is it possible for you do something like the  binocular stereo vision? In this case, you may obtain the extra **depth information** that is not included in any single camera, and maybe helpful for the recognition task.

Comment: I am not quite sure about the depth part (if it will be indeed useful). However the thing bugging me since many days is how to actually combine the different views, do I need to do something like just append the other view to the first view and feed two images to the Neural network instead of one, or use something like ResNet, DenseNet architecture ?